# use 'diff-highlight' for diff

Tags: git, diff

I have set up [diff-highlight](https://github.com/git/git/tree/master/contrib/diff-highlight) as pager / highlighter for git.

```
[pager]
    log = diff-highlight | less
    show = diff-highlight | less
    diff = diff-highlight | less
```

That works perfectly.

But how can I use diff-highlight for normal diff ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define a function:

```
diff() { /usr/bin/diff "$@" | diff-highlight }
```

`diff-highlight` processes unified diffs (`diff -u`) but piping other formats appears to work — it passes them through unchanged.

To approximate the behaviour you get with `git diff`, you’d need [`colordiff`](http://www.colordiff.org/) too:

```
diff() { colordiff -u "$@" | diff-highlight | less -FRX }
```

Comment: thanks, but that does not work as it is. If I add '-u' to diff, then it works in monochrome. I had to change '/usr/bin/diff' to  '/usr/bin/colordiff' to get what I want. I am not sure why your example works for you, but not for me.

Comment: You asked how to use `diff-highlight` with normal `diff` ;-). Could you expand your question to make it explicit what you’re looking for? Is it something like “I want to run `diff fileA fileB` and see output similar to what I get with `git diff fileA` after configuring `git` with `diff-highlight`, including colours and paging”?